# Is it possible to receive dhcpdiscover from ff:ff:ff... mac address?

Tags: networking, dhcp, ethernet

Today I saw this record in my log files:

```
dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff via vlan400: network 40.60.100.10/24: no free leases                                                                                                              
dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff via vlan300: network 100.100.120.0/24: no free leases
```

And so on, on all VLANs connected to the same ethernet card em1.

I am 99% sure that I have no devices on these VLANs which are able to send DHCP requests.

Also ff:ff:ff is a strange MAC.

So, my question is:  is it something bad? Some errors on the ethernet-card or switch or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is at least something weird. `ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff` is the broadcast mac address. Neither a broadcast nor a multicast address may be used as the source address for Ethernet frames as per IEEE 802.3 as it does not uniquely identify the originator:

IEEE 802.3-2002, Section 3.2.3(b):

> The first bit (LSB) shall be used in the Destination Address field as an 
>   address type designation bit to identify the Destination Address either 
>   as an individual or as a group address. If this bit is 0, it shall 
>   indicate that the address field contains an individual address. If this 
>   bit is 1, it shall indicate that the address eld contains a group 
>   address that identies none, one or more, or all of the stations connected 
>   to the LAN. In the Source Address field, the first bit is reserved and 
>   set to 0.

It is very likely that something is misconfigured in your network and you should start looking for where exactly those frames / packets are originating.